# How to remove redundant records in the given table, using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How to remove redundant records in the given table, using SQL?

```
FROM   |  TO      | TIME
========================
USA    |  CHINA   | 4
USA    |  AFRICA  | 2
CHINA  |  USA     | 4
CALI   |  NEWZLND | 3
```

Here the USA to CHINA & CHINA TO USA are redundant records, I require only one of them to be in the final table. How must I phrase an sql query for this?

Comment: Can you show us the tables you have,anything you have tried so far, any code that we can help you with? Anything else other then end result?

Comment: And please do not post pictures. Better you post something we can copy and paste. Otherwise it is very hard for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this.

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c3211/2

Btw: Changed your column names. Do not use reserved words like FROM, TO and TIME...

```
CREATE TABLE tbl(FromColumn VARCHAR(100),ToColumn VARCHAR(100),TIMEColumn INT);

INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
 ('USA','CHINA',4)
,('USA','AFRICA',2)
,('CHINA','USA',4)
,('CALI','NEWZLND',3);

SELECT *
FROM tbl AS tbl
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) 
       FROM tbl AS x
       WHERE x.FromColumn>x.ToColumn
         AND x.FromColumn=tbl.ToColumn
         AND x.ToColumn=tbl.FromColumn 
         AND x.TIMEColumn=tbl.TIMEColumn
       )=0;
```

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you have a reflexive relationship, similar to "Person1 is a friend of Person2" - where it's implied that "Person2 is a friend of Person1", and you don't want to store both records. Assuming that it doesn't matter which one you store, you can delete the duplicates. Here, I keep the one where Person1 comes before Person2:

```
CREATE TABLE Friendship(
    Person1     varchar(128),
    Person2     varchar(128),
    PRIMARY KEY(Person1, Person2)
);  

DELETE FROM Friendship
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT  *
    FROM    Friendship as reflex
    WHERE   Friendship.Person1 = reflex.Person2
      AND   Friendship.Person2 = reflex.Person1
      AND   Friendship.Person2 < Friendship.Person2
);
```

Comment: Sorry I missed your image (you didn't title it) but my solution still addresses your problem by deleting the redundant records. You could do the same with a SELECT too.